# Importing data from excel to database mysql - how to insert cmd DateTime parameter in format yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss

Tags: c#, mysql, .net, excel, datetime

This time i've created like "Sheet5" in excel Workbook:

[image]

When I load data from this excel to datagridview i get this view (in datagridview of course):

```
    +--------+---------+---------+-------------+---------+----------+----------+---------------------------+----------------+
    |FNAME |LNAME  |ORDER_DESC|ORDER_NUMBER|MODULE NAME|PROJECT NAME|AMOUNT_OF_PRODUCTS|   BEGIN_DATE     |    END_DATE     |
    +--------+---------+---------+---------+------------+-----------+----------+--------------------------------------------+
    |Jonhy | Blank | make sth |    e/1     |S-BOX      |    box     |       20         | 22.05.2019 06:32 | 22.05.2019 15:13|
    +--------+---------+---------+----------------------+-----------+----------+--------------------------------------------+
```

Then I'd like to insert to MYSQL database:

```
for (int i = 0; i < datagrdStatus_order.Rows.Count; i++)
{
MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("INSERT INTO project1.order_status(ID_WORKER, ID_ORDER, ID_MODULE, ID_PROJECT, AMOUNT_OF_PRODUCTS, BEGIN_DATE, END_DATE) SELECT workers.ID_WORKER, orders.ID_ORDER, module.ID_MODULE, projects.ID, @AMOUNT_OF_PRODUCTS, @BEGIN_DATE, @END_DATE FROM project1.workers INNER JOIN project1.orders INNER JOIN project1.modules INNER JOIN project1.projects WHERE workers.FNAME = @FNAME AND workers.LNAME = @LNAME AND orders.ORDER_DESC = @ORDER_DESC AND orders.ORDER_NUMBER = @ORDER_NUMBER AND modules.NAME = @MODULES_NAME AND projects.PROJECT_NAME = @PROJECT_NAME", connection);
cmd.Parameters.Add("@FNAME", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = datagrdStatus_order.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value.ToString();
cmd.Parameters.Add("@LNAME", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = datagrdStatus_order.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value.ToString();
cmd.Parameters.Add("@ORDER_DESC", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = datagrdStatus_order.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value.ToString();
cmd.Parameters.Add("@ORDER_NUMBER", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = datagrdStatus_order.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value.ToString();
cmd.Parameters.Add("@MODULES_NAME", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = datagrdStatus_order.Rows[i].Cells[4].Value.ToString();
cmd.Parameters.Add("@PROJECT_NAME", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = datagrdStatus_order.Rows[i].Cells[5].Value.ToString();
cmd.Parameters.Add("@AMOUNT_OF_PRODUCTS", MySqlDbType.Int64).Value = datagrdStatus_order.Rows[i].Cells[6].Value.ToString();
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BEGIN_DATE", MySqlDbType.DateTime).Value = datagrdStatus_order.Rows[i].Cells[7].Value.ToString();
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@END_DATE", MySqlDbType.DateTime).Value = datagrdStatus_order.Rows[i].Cells[8].Value.ToString();
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

That above code insert most of data to database but by as for as `BEGIN_DATE` AND `END_DATE` are concerned i get error exception that these values are inserted as NULL (in sense is like 0000-00-00 00:00:00).

But when i'm trying inserting 2 these DateTimes like this:

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BEGIN_DATE", MySqlDbType.DateTime).Value = datagrdStatus_order.Rows[i].Cells[7].Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@END_DATE", MySqlDbType.DateTime).Value = datagrdStatus_order.Rows[i].Cells[8].Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
```

I get error:

> No overloading of the "ToString" method takes the following number of
>   arguments: "1"

that trouble is here:

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BEGIN_DATE", MySqlDbType.DateTime).Value = datagrdStatus_order.Rows[i].Cells[7].Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@END_DATE", MySqlDbType.DateTime).Value = datagrdStatus_order.Rows[i].Cells[8].Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
```

I don't know what can i do? Can i count someone for any help? Thx in advance.

There is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;
using System.Collections;
using System.Data.OleDb;
using System.IO;
using System.Configuration;

namespace ControlDataBase
{
    public partial class New_Tables : Form
    {
        public New_Tables()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        Form1 frm1 = (Form1)Application.OpenForms["Form1"];

        private void btnClose_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Close();
        }

        private void ImportData_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            using (OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog() { Filter = "Excel Files|*.xlsx;*.xlsm;*.xlsb;*.xltx;*.xltm;*.xls;*.xlt;*.xls;*.xml;*.xml;*.xlam;*.xla;*.xlw;*.xlr;", ValidateNames = true })
            {
                if (ofd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
                {
                    FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(ofd.FileName);
                    string FileName1 = ofd.FileName;

                    string excel = fi.FullName;

                    if (ofd.FileName.EndsWith(".xlsx"))
                    {
                        StrConn = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + excel + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0;\"";
                    }

                    if (ofd.FileName.EndsWith(".xls"))
                    {
                        StrConn = @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + excel + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 1.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1\"";
                    }
                    OleDbConnection oledbconn = new OleDbConnection(StrConn);

                    OleDbDataAdapter dta5 = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM [Sheet5$]", oledbconn);
                    oledbconn.Open();

                    DataSet dsole5 = new DataSet();
                    dta5.Fill(dsole5, "Sheet5$");
                    datagrdStatus_order.DataSource = dsole5.Tables["Sheet5$"];

                    oledbconn.Close();

                    MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection("datasource=localhost;port=3306;username=root;password=");
                    connection.Open();

                    for (int i = 0; i < datagrdStatus_order.Rows.Count; i++)
                    {
                        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("INSERT INTO project1.order_status(ID_WORKER, ID_ORDER, ID_MODULE, ID_PROJECT, AMOUNT_OF_PRODUCTS, BEGIN_DATE, END_DATE) SELECT workers.ID_WORKER, orders.ID_ORDER, module.ID_MODULE, projects.ID, @AMOUNT_OF_PRODUCTS, @BEGIN_DATE, @END_DATE FROM project1.workers INNER JOIN project1.orders INNER JOIN project1.modules INNER JOIN project1.projects WHERE workers.FNAME = @FNAME AND workers.LNAME = @LNAME AND orders.ORDER_DESC = @ORDER_DESC AND orders.ORDER_NUMBER = @ORDER_NUMBER AND modules.NAME = @MODULES_NAME AND projects.PROJECT_NAME = @PROJECT_NAME", connection);
                        cmd.Parameters.Add("@FNAME", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = datagrdStatus_order.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value.ToString();
                        cmd.Parameters.Add("@LNAME", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = datagrdStatus_order.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value.ToString();
                        cmd.Parameters.Add("@ORDER_DESC", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = datagrdStatus_order.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value.ToString();
                        cmd.Parameters.Add("@ORDER_NUMBER", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = datagrdStatus_order.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value.ToString();
                        cmd.Parameters.Add("@MODULES_NAME", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = datagrdStatus_order.Rows[i].Cells[4].Value.ToString();
                        cmd.Parameters.Add("@PROJECT_NAME", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = datagrdStatus_order.Rows[i].Cells[5].Value.ToString();
                        cmd.Parameters.Add("@AMOUNT_OF_PRODUCTS", MySqlDbType.Int64).Value = datagrdStatus_order.Rows[i].Cells[6].Value.ToString();
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BEGIN_DATE", MySqlDbType.DateTime).Value = datagrdStatus_order.Rows[i].Cells[7].Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@END_DATE", MySqlDbType.DateTime).Value = datagrdStatus_order.Rows[i].Cells[8].Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
                        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    }
                    connection.Close();
                    MessageBox.Show("The data are imported correctly");

                    loaddataalldatagridview();
                }
            }
        }

        private void loaddataalldatagridview()
        {
            frm1.loaddata5();
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

I've modified the "for datagridview" loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < datagrdStatus_order.Rows.Count; i++)
                    {
                        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("INSERT INTO project1.order_status(ID_WORKER, ID_ORDER, ID_MODULE, ID_PROJECT, AMOUNT_OF_PRODUCTS, BEGIN_DATE, END_DATE) SELECT workers.ID_WORKER, orders.ID_ORDER, module.ID_MODULE, projects.ID, @AMOUNT_OF_PRODUCTS, @BEGIN_DATE, @END_DATE FROM project1.workers INNER JOIN project1.orders INNER JOIN project1.modules INNER JOIN project1.projects WHERE workers.FNAME = @FNAME AND workers.LNAME = @LNAME AND orders.ORDER_DESC = @ORDER_DESC AND orders.ORDER_NUMBER = @ORDER_NUMBER AND modules.NAME = @MODULES_NAME AND projects.PROJECT_NAME = @PROJECT_NAME", connection);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FNAME", datagrdStatus_order.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LNAME", datagrdStatus_order.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ORDER_DESC", datagrdStatus_order.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NUMBER_ORDER", datagrdStatus_order.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MODULES_NAME", datagrdStatus_order.Rows[i].Cells[4].Value);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PROJECT_NAME", datagrdStatus_order.Rows[i].Cells[5].Value);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AMOUNT_OF_PRODUCTS", datagrdStatus_order.Rows[i].Cells[6].Value);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BEGIN_DATE", (DateTime)datagrdStatus_order.Rows[i].Cells[7].Value);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@END_DATE", (DateTime)datagrdStatus_order.Rows[i].Cells[8].Value);
                    }
```

But then i got shown exception:

> System.NullReferenceException: "The object reference has not been set
>   to the instance of the object."
>   System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCell.Value.get returned null.

exactly at the line of code:

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BEGIN_DATE", (DateTime)datagrdStatus_order.Rows[i].Cells[7].Value);
```

Can i count for any help this time? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, i was thinking about that solution and i've just found it (in below) on my own thx for any help :).

```
for (int i = 0; i < datagrdStatus_order.Rows.Count; i++)
                    {
                        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("INSERT INTO project1.order_status(ID_WORKER, ID_ORDER, ID_MODULE, ID_PROJECT, AMOUNT_OF_PRODUCTS, BEGIN_DATE, END_DATE) SELECT workers.ID_WORKER, orders.ID_ORDER, module.ID_MODULE, projects.ID, @AMOUNT_OF_PRODUCTS, @BEGIN_DATE, @END_DATE FROM project1.workers INNER JOIN project1.orders INNER JOIN project1.modules INNER JOIN project1.projects WHERE workers.FNAME = @FNAME AND workers.LNAME = @LNAME AND orders.ORDER_DESC = @ORDER_DESC AND orders.ORDER_NUMBER = @ORDER_NUMBER AND modules.NAME = @MODULES_NAME AND projects.PROJECT_NAME = @PROJECT_NAME", connection);
                    DateTime begin_date = Convert.ToDateTime(datagrdStatus_zl.Rows[i].Cells[7].Value);
                    DateTime end_date = Convert.ToDateTime(datagrdStatus_zl.Rows[i].Cells[8].Value);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FNAME", datagrdStatus_order.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LNAME", datagrdStatus_order.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ORDER_DESC", datagrdStatus_order.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NUMBER_ORDER", datagrdStatus_order.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MODULES_NAME", datagrdStatus_order.Rows[i].Cells[4].Value);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PROJECT_NAME", datagrdStatus_order.Rows[i].Cells[5].Value);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AMOUNT_OF_PRODUCTS", datagrdStatus_order.Rows[i].Cells[6].Value);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BEGIN_DATE", begin_date);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@END_DATE", end_date);
                    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably `datagrdStatus_order.Rows[i].Cells[X].Value` returns `òbject`, not a `DateTime` for your that columns. Since [`Object.ToString` method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.object.tostring?view=netframework-4.8) doesn't have an overload that takes string as a parameter, that's why you get this error.

> No overloading of the "ToString" method takes the following number of
>   arguments: "1"

That's why you need to cast it first - if you can't, parse it - then you need to assign it like;

```
if(datagrdStatus_order.Rows[i].Cells[7].Value is DateTime)
   cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BEGIN_DATE", MySqlDbType.DateTime).Value = 
                                 (DateTime)datagrdStatus_order.Rows[i].Cells[7].Value;
```

Or you can parse it to directly (preferable with `DateTime.ParseExact`) which matters the format by the way.

Comment: Do you mean to modify the last 2 line codes in "for datagrdStatus_order" loop?

Comment: But wait - i've modified the last 2 line codes in these "for loop"  to this:
`                        if (datagrdStatus_zl.Rows[i].Cells[7].Value is DateTime)
                           cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BEGIN_DATE", MySqlDbType.DateTime).Value = (DateTime)datagrdStatus_zl.Rows[i].Cells[7].Value;
                        if (datagrdStatus_zl.Rows[i].Cells[8].Value is DateTime)
                            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@END_DATE", MySqlDbType.DateTime).Value = (DateTime)datagrdStatus_zl.Rows[i].Cells[8].Value;`

Comment: then i get `System.InvalidCastException: Incorrect projection from the 'DateTime' element to the 'Int32' element.